# Is there a way to set npm intellisense to work including packages from package-lock.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, intellisense, package.json

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure `npm intellisense` on VSCode to work observing modules not specified in package.json, but its dependencies, since they're already installed and listed within package-lock.json?

In more detail:
My current project utilizes a custom-made framework, which already utilizes some dependencies like `moment` and `lodash`, for example. However, my package.json's dependency list is similar to this:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "custom-framework": "5.0.2"
}
```

So naturally, npm intellisense won't autocomplete imports for `lodash` or `moment`, however they're listed with package-lock.json as dependencies of `custom-framework`. I wish to enable `npm intellisense` to check for the dependencies used by `custom-framework` without adding them as deps on my package.json dependency list. Is this possible?

I know that installing the dependencies directly as dependencies of the project solves this issue, but I was wondering if there's any way to enable this coverage on npm intellisense's configuration, or maybe a similar extension that could solve this one issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the fact that at runtime, lodash and moment are accessible to your package through commonjs module resolution is more of a coincidence I think. If you were using PNPM, you'd need to (intentionally, by design) declare those as direct dependencies of your package. Are you sure that you aren't getting intellisense for moment? moment bundles type definitions, whereas with lodash, you go through DefinitelyTyped. Also, show your package.json's `type` property and your tsconfig.json